# How to download all files from a cvs repository?

Tags: cvs

I installed maccvsclient and try to download files from sourceforge.

I have logged in using

```
cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@mconverter.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/project login
```

but how to download the all files with directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you login;

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@mconverter.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/mconverter co -P mconverter
```